# HTML5 Boilerplate: is it possible to inline @import for multiple stylesheets with the build script?

Tags: css, ant, build, import, html5boilerplate

Currently, the [H5BP ant build script](https://github.com/h5bp/ant-build-script/blob/master/build.xml) (line 817) takes "style.css" and inlines the imports specified there. However, I'd like to have this functionality for multiple stylesheets. My current directory structure is like this:

```
css/
    h5bp/
        h5bp.normalize.css
        h5bp.helper.classes.css
        h5bp.media.queries.css
        h5bp.print.css
    pages/
        home.page.styles.css
        about.page.styles.css
        upload.page.styles.css
        download.page.styles.css
        ...
    extras/
        ie.styles.css
        layout.styles.css
        font.styles.css
        ...
```

I'd like to be able to run the css ant target for each file in the `css/pages/` directory such that each stylesheet has the imports inlined and then is minified. Does the current H5BP build script support this functionality? If not, how would I modify it to fit my needs? An example stylesheet looks like this...

```
@import url(../h5bp/h5bp.normalize.css);
@import url(../extras/ie.styles.css);
@import url(../extras/layout.styles.css);

/* this stylesheet is specific for the "home page" */
@import url(home.page.styles.css);

@import url(../extras/font.styles.css);
@import url(../h5bp/h5bp.helper.classes.css);
@import url(../h5bp/h5bp.media.queries.css);
@import url(../h5bp/h5bp.print.css);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We only recommend having a single stylesheet as this would be appropriate for most common use cases. Hence we do not have anything that would allow this kind of behaviour that you require.

However, the [node build script should be able to do this for you](https://github.com/h5bp/node-build-script/wiki/css).

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at the node build script. I'm just wondering, though, why you recommend only a single stylesheet? Wouldn't that result in many unnecessary styles and a performance hit? For example, my "home" page shouldn't care about the styles in the "about" page and vice versa... but you're suggesting that the "home" page and the "about" page styles should all be in one massive style.css file?

Comment: If you combine your stylesheets into one sheet it reduces the number http requests. There are tools such as [Closure Stylesheets](http://code.google.com/p/closure-stylesheets/) that allow you to keep your stylesheets separate in your project and then automatically combine and minify them for release.

Comment: The time it takes for a network request to process (from the beginning of the request to time it takes to download) is significantly more than the time it takes a browser to parse a stylesheet and render the appropriate styles.