# @import to minify and concatenate CSS not working with h5bp build script

Tags: css, build, html5boilerplate

I've set up my `main.css` to import to two style sheets using the @import rule so the H5BP build script will minify and concatenate them.  How ever all I get after running the build script is a minified version of the `main.css` without the two imported files.

I've checked the build scrips config and it's pointing to the right file and I've also tried changing the paths relativity with no success.

here is the main.css :

```
@import url("../css/html5bp.css");
@import url("../css/styles.css");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This appears to have already been answered:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804847/html5-boilerplate-is-it-possible-to-inline-import-for-multiple-stylesheets-wit

Comment: @KnowHowSolutions No, that answer regards generating multiple concatenated style sheets.

Comment: It's still the right answer for you, even if the original question's goal is different.  The goal is to create one CSS file, and minify it, to reduce the number of requests and the size of the request.  It references this build script [https://github.com/h5bp/node-build-script/wiki/css] which does what you ask (almost verbatim too, concatenate and minify).

Comment: @KnowHowSolutions As far as I understand, this is supported in the ANT build script without need for the node build script. This is the part I'm refering to : `Inlines stylesheets specified using @import in your CSS
Combines and minifies CSS (using YUI Compressor)`

Answer (score 0):

There might be an issue with using relative paths, there was a post to githug about this a few months ago.

Line 763 of the build script xml file appears to be where this starts and does appear to support what you are looking for.  I'd suggest trying a full path for your imports and seeing if that works.

Comment: Ah interesting, I was thinking in server terms.  I assumed the build script would take the project folder as it's root.  I'll give it ago tomorrow morning. Thanks!

Comment: No joy :( In the docs it does say the @imports should be relative to the `main.css` .

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the `build/config/default.properties` file, you can find the following script:

```
#
# Root Stylesheet
# this is the file that contains the @import directives
#
file.root.stylesheet    = main.css
```